# Adding Progress Bar in symfony 2.1

Tags: php, symfony, progress-bar

I have a symfony form with file upload option. 
So how can i add the progress bar in this form.
I have tried with AJAX but not got success.

```
$(".loading").show();

$.ajax({
    url: {
        {
            path('myroute')
            }
        },
        data: $("#form1").serialize(),
        type: "POST",
        success: function (response) {
            if (response != 'Success') {
                alert(response);
            } else {
                if ($("#return").is(":checked") == true)
                    redirect("pages_add.php?res=add_success");
                else
                    redirect("pages_manager.php?res=add_success");
            }

            $(".loading").hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you actually tried?

Answer (score 0):

This one can help: http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload-with-progress-bar-using-jquery/

As well as several others, which can be found on the net.

P.S.
You don't need to use jQuery necessarily, for example, I've built the same widget using YUI3.

P.P.S
Generally progress bar will work only in modern browsers (which support FileAPI)

Something like

```
if (!!window.FileReader) {
    // modern code here
}
```

will help to determine which browser type you are dealing with.